# Vis.js Timeline - How to collapse a group without nesting

Tags: javascript, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'd like to be able to collapse or toggle visibility of specific groups on the timeline by clicking on the group title (or an icon next to it, etc.)

All examples I've seen for accomplishing similar functionality requires using nested groups, and then collapsing the group, but the nested model does not work for our data, and we only want to be able to collapse one at a time.

I have figured how to show a group as collapsed on initialization by setting a className, but I haven't figured out how to toggle the className on the group label + row on the fly.

Comment: `All examples I've seen for accomplishing similar functionality requires using nested groups`. That's because it's the best way to do it.  `but the nested model does not work for our data`. Why not? Is it because you don't get if unnested from the server? If so nothing prevents you from creating your own nested model on the client.

Comment: @Geert-Jan it doesn't make sense for us, because our groups aren't "grouped" themselves -- we only have one level in our hierarchy of groups

Comment: Ah apologies, reading again 'groups' in this context is a vis.js specific thing, not some grouping in a general data-structure sense. Not sure, but would you be able to attach a click event-handler to the group to toggle the mentioned className?

Comment: @Geert-Jan yep, just trying to get help with how to access the groups after they've been initialized, because I see no method on the module to retrieve the groups (they are not simply dom elements). and I don't see any indication in the documentation that you can change the group properties on the fly. in vis.js, the groups are the rows of the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

I uses thise functions in order to remove/show all items in a group

```
    function plannerCloseGroup(groupID){
    // retrieve all items having a property group with value groupID
    var itemsFiltered = items.get({
      filter: function (item) {
        return (item.group == groupID);
      }
    });
    closedItems[groupID] = itemsFiltered;
    items.remove(itemsFiltered);
    $("#plannerMinus_" + groupID).addClass("hidden");
    $("#plannerMinus_" + groupID).removeClass("display");
    $("#plannerPlus_" + groupID).removeClass("hidden");
    $("#plannerPlus_"+ groupID).addClass("display");
}

function plannerOpenGroup(groupID){
    items.update(closedItems[groupID]);
    $("#plannerMinus_" + groupID).addClass("display");
    $("#plannerMinus_" + groupID).removeClass("hidden");
    $("#plannerPlus_" + groupID).removeClass("display");
    $("#plannerPlus_" + groupID).addClass("hidden");
    delete closedItems[groupID];
}
```

closedItems is a global array

plannerMinus og plannerPlus are icons next to the group name

When I define my groups I have this code in content, where $employeeID also is my groupID

```
'<span id="plannerPlus_'.$employeeID.'" class="hidden"><img src="images/planner-plus-grey.gif" width=10 height=10 onclick="plannerOpenGroup('.$employeeID.')"> </span><span id="plannerMinus_'.$employeeID.'" class="display"><img src="images/planner-minus.gif" width=10 height=10 onclick="plannerCloseGroup('.$employeeID.')"> </span>'
```

It then looks like this
[image: open group]
[image: closed group]